# Does menstruation affect the ability of women to do blue-collar work?

Tags: physiology, gender, productivity, menstrual-cycle

I just read about the concept of [menstrual leave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_leave). The Wikipedia article says it originated in Japan, and applies in a couple of asian countries.

In 2005, Australian Manufacturing Workers Union secretary Doug Cameron [asked](http://www.smh.com.au/news/Breaking-News/AMWU-promotes-menstrual-leave/2005/02/11/1108061833151.html?oneclick=true) for menstrual leave to be available for women working at Toyota (in Australia):

> "Many women have excessive cramps, many women have headaches, many
>   women have nausea, many women can't concentrate and they're on a
>   production line," he said.
>
> "It's a tough, hot dangerous job and we believe that this is a
>   sensible claim that's good for the company because it will improve
>   productivity, it will improve quality and it will improve health and
>   safety."

Does menstruation affect the ability of a significant number of women to do blue-collar work?

Comment: What is your question? Whether women do have period cramps and other problems or whether these are bad enough to prevent them from working meaningfully?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there are jobs you're not (fully) capable of doing while having the mood swings, cramps, and other symptoms many women encounter to some degree during menstruation. I seriously doubt though whether there's been scientific study into the subject, feminists would complain too loudly and call the study an excuse for discrimination based on sex.

Comment: @jwenting while some people would find the concept offensive, I don't think feminists would be able to totally prevent such research.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I'm less optimistic about the ability of scientists to perform research that vocal activist groups don't like or fear the likely results of than you are.

Comment: As a feminist I do not see any problem in doing such research if it can cause better opportunities in jobs,sports and the other activities for women equal to men as they are doing same activities and in many cases show better abilities and gain higher results than men though they have period cramps and other problems related their special biological condition so I think they deserve more and higher wages and rewards in similar situations with men at work or sport or management.

Comment: Women get pregnant, and some women have very painful menstrual cramps (the contractions inhibit blood flow to the lining of the uterus. It hurts). It's biology. I don't think 'feminists would complain too loudly' unless it's given a bad use. In fact, Clara Zetkin (she organized the first International Women's Day) supported this sort of legislation. My granma worked for a factory and had menstrual leave (1 day a month). This was in the 40s, and there was no ibuprofen. Any answer should probably also investigate the incidence of pain relief medicine!

Comment: Some groups (mainly in Asia) opposed these measures because they were linked to definitions of women’s citizenship that primarily emphasized their maternal roles (Yuval-Davis and Anthias, 1989). Similar notions to ‘the family wage’ that entitled men to higher wages in their role as principal breadwinners (Jansz, 1995). [[Source](https://crawford.anu.edu.au/pdf/staff/rmap/lahiridutt/JA3_KLD_Robinson_Period_Problems.pdf)]

Comment: @Yisela in which country did your grandma work?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Sorry, I forgot to mention it. She worked in Argentina, I'm guessing during the first government of Peron, which might explain the existence of such a 'luxury'. I'm trying to find more information about it.

Comment: Not all women have really bad periods. Not all non-women have a 100% health record. If someone has dreadful pain which stops them from working, it is not necessary to say "this is a woman-thing".